# Counting Records within a time duration

Tags: mysql

I have a table of pool league match results with both match_begin_time and match_end_time fields of type TIME.

I want to know how many records fall into various time duration intervals, i.e., < 1 Hour, 1 Hour to 1.5 Hours, etc.

I tried the following code to grab the 1st 2 intervals, but each one returned all the records irrespective of the time interval between Begin and End:

{

```
SELECT
     COUNT(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN time("00:00:00") AND time("00:59:59")) AS "< 1 Hour",
     COUNT(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN time("01:00:00") AND time("01:30:00")) AS "1 - 1.5 Hours"
FROM   lwljhb_lwl_matches
WHERE
     match_end_time > 0 AND
     match_end_time > 0 AND
     match_end_time > Match_begin_time
```

}

Using the WHERE clause I can run the query once for each time interval and I get the right answer. For example, the following code correctly returns the 4 records where the duration is < 1 hour.

{

```
SELECT 
     TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) AS "< 1 Hour"
FROM   lwljhb_lwl_matches
WHERE
     match_end_time > 0 AND
     match_end_time > 0 AND
     match_end_time > Match_begin_time AND
     TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN time("00:00:00") AND time("00:59:59")
```

}

Where am I going wrong in my COUNT expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the boolean expression within my COUNT yields a 1 (true) or a 0 (false). COUNT sees both of these as non_NULL and counts them. I was thinking (incorrectly) that it would only count the 1s (trues). Further research showed me two ways to resolve this, using COUNT & IF or SUM.

```
COUNT(IF(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN time("00:00:00") AND time("00:59:59"), 1, NULL)) AS "
```

```
SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN time("00:00:00") AND time("00:59:59") AS "
```

The second eliminates the need for the IF because the booleans are treated as integers and the 1s (trues) increase the sum and the 0s (falses) don't. The NULLs are ignored.

So, my whole query is:

```
SELECT
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '00:00:01' AND '01:00:00' ) AS '<1 Hour',
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '01:00:01' AND '01:30:00' ) AS '1 - 1.5 Hours',
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '01:30:01' AND '02:00:00' ) AS '1.5 - 2 Hours',
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '02:00:01' AND '02:30:00' ) AS '2 - 2.5 Hours',
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '02:30:01' AND '03:00:00' ) AS '2.5 - 3 Hours',
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '03:00:01' AND '03:30:00' ) AS '3 - 3.5 Hours',
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '03:30:01' AND '04:00:00' ) AS '3.5 - 4 Hours',
     SUM(TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN '04:00:01' AND '10:00:00' ) AS '> 4 Hours'
FROM lwljhb_lwl_matches
```

Answer (score 4):

I will give you a simple query to display the count of records fall into time interval '< 1 Hour' and '1 Hour to 1.5 Hours'. I think it will helpful for you.

```
SELECT x.a AS '<1 Hour', y.b AS '1- 1.5 Hours'
FROM (SELECT COUNT(TIMEDIFF (match_end_time, match_begin_time)) AS a
       FROM lwljhb_lwl_matches 
       WHERE TIMEDIFF (match_end_time, match_begin_time)<'01:00:00') as x, 
     (SELECT COUNT(TIMEDIFF (match_end_time, match_begin_time)) AS b
       FROM lwljhb_lwl_matches 
       WHERE TIMEDIFF(match_end_time, match_begin_time) BETWEEN'01:00:00' AND '01:30:00') AS y
```

You can use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(TIMEDIFF (match_end_time, match_begin_time))` will produce the same result.
Likewise, You can find records of other time intervals. You can check my code in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67a861/2).

Comment: This works, though it's pretty similar to what I had in mind when I said I could just run the query for each interval. What I'm looking for is the answer to my actual question, What's wrong with the COUNT expressions?

Comment: The problem is that you have given a condition with COUNT expression. I think it will give a boolean result. That's why you didn't get the desired result.

Comment: I thought that in MySQL booleans were treated as integers, i.e., True=1 and False-0. That way the Counting would work, but it doesn't. Turns out that since both 1 and 0 are non-NULL, they get counted and every COUNT yields a count of all non-NULL records. I need to use COUNT & IF or SUM. Se my answer to my question.